# Resources in custom iOS frameworks

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios8, frameworks, resources

I have made an empty single-view application in Xcode 6 (FWTest) and added a Cocoa Touch Framework (FWTestKit) as a target and asked it to embed in FWTest. Then I add an image (photo.png) to the framework, that I expect to be in Frameworks/FWTestKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/photo.png when I build & archive my app. However, I find it in Frameworks/FWTestKit.framework/photo.png

How can I make it at least be in a Resources folder? Preferably a versioned folder so I can ship different versions of my framework?

When I add this framework to another app, do I need to do anything special to make sure the resources are bundled along with it, so that when I reference a resource from within my framework I can be sure it'll be available also when used in another app?

Cheers

Nik

Comment: Source code is here, for good measure: https://www.dropbox.com/s/v741euhuh2llyzm/FWTest.zip?dl=0

Comment: And when doing xcodebuild from the command line, the confusing line is: "CopyPNGFile build/Release-iphoneos/FWTestKit.framework/photo.png FWTestKit/photo.png"

Comment: You should rethink your architecture so that you don't need to care about the path of photo.png on disk. That method won't scale well at all.

Comment: I get the path via NSBundle.resourcePath(), so no architectural problem there. I just want my framework directory structure to look like a framework is supposed to look, not just jumbled together in the frameworks root folder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: step1] [image: If the desired structure is]![step2]You should add your photo.png into separate folder (let's call it "gica" ). Then drag folder into project, check Copy items if needed and create folder reference. Then (important) in build phases, drag photo.png again in Copy Bundle Resources, keeping  Copy items if needed and create folder references. After you compile you should have now desired folder structure [It is keeping gica/photo.png].[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to revise the architecture about versioning. Anyway if you still need to place the image inside the folder. Try creating a run script.

In your build phases instead of adding your images to copy bundle resource phase. You can create a shell script to copy your images to desired folder. Please note build phases are run in the order they placed. My point is you can customise xCode Build process through your own shell scripts.